# My code nests too deep. Is there a better way?

Tags: python

This particular code I wrote in another question recently, and I'm not sure it's optimal. I couldn't find a less-indented way of doing this though. Is there?

```
def msg_generator(self):
    ''' Provides messages until bot dies '''
    while self.alive:
        for msg in self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode()):
            if len(msg) > 3:
                try: 
                    yield Message(msg.decode())
                except Exception as e:
                    self.log('%s %s\n' % (except_str, str(e)))
```

I keep hearing that nesting too much is bad, but this seems to be necessary. It's currently four indentations deep.

Comment: That's not too nested. Large, highly nested functions may have readability problems, but this doesn't.

Comment: ignacio, i count five

Comment: @flow Well, I ignored the definition indent as well as the class indent (noted by having self present) which would make it 6. But, those two I can tolerate and can't really get around.

Comment: you're right, well, that makes it seven, then. i start to believe that maybe it's really too deeply nested

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can do this:

```
def msg_generator(self):
    ''' Provides messages until bot dies '''
    while self.alive:
        for msg in self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode()):

            if len(msg) <= 3:
                continue

            try: 
                yield Message(msg.decode())
            except Exception as e:
                self.log('%s %s\n' % (except_str, str(e)))
```

Or you could refactor into functions.

```
def msg_generator(self):
    ''' Provides messages until bot dies '''
    while self.alive:
        for msg in self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode()):

            if not len(msg) > 3:
                continue

            yield handle_message(msg)

def handle_message(msg):
    try: 
        return Message(msg.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        self.log('%s %s\n' % (except_str, str(e)))
```

Or use something like this:

```
from itertools import imap

def msg_generator(self):
    ''' Provides messages until bot dies '''
    while self.alive:
        it = iter(self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode()))
        return imap(handle_message, (msg for msg in it if len(msg) > 3)

def handle_message(msg):
    try: 
        return Message(msg.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        self.log('%s %s\n' % (except_str, str(e)))
```

The last option is not perfect, because if there is an exception then the func will return `None` which is not a real message, so You could also filter that afterwards using `filter()` or have the other end handle `None` msg's.

Comment: @OneOfOne: Boundary issues with non-integral lengths. *runs*

Comment: Yes, I typically find that negative logic fixes it and for some reason forgot about it on this one. Thank you, that dropped it down to three indentations. I'm thinking refactoring into functions could possibly cause slight overhead and this is a generator that sometimes yields several thousand objects per second. I could always test it with timeit, but I'm pretty convinced it would add overhead.

Comment: wah never worry about that overheadish thingie. good performance is but one code consideration. readability and sustainability are other important factors. a good API will make it easier to spot problem zones later on. also, if you're concerned about performance, change that message-splitting clause as indicated in my answer.

Comment: `len( x ) > 3` is OK as `len` is a built-in which either returns an integral non-negative number or throws an error. there is no boundary issues to worry about here.

Answer (score 4):

the problem with the code above is not so much that it is nested too deeply, it is more that the code is too *extensional*, not enough *intentional*. by this i mean that while the cogs and wheels and levers that you need to assemble your machinery are in place and (presumably) do work, there are too few labeled modules in sight—there are too many concerns 'complected' in too many implicit, unlabeled ways, resulting in hard-to-read code (for that 'complect' part, do you the favor to listen to http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy —it's a very enlightening talk, and it puts the finger on the problems with your code).

let me give an example:

```
...
for msg in self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode()):
...
```

i take it you're talking about 'messages' here. so why not call that variable `message`? why abbrv. that word? `message` is so much clearer.

now it's `for message in xxx`. what is `xxx`? well, you already know. in Pythonic English, it is true, most of the time, that `for apple in appples; for pear in pears` should be a good, reasonably semantic way of writing things: the `for ... in` loop singles out elements, one at a time, out of a collection of elements, so `for <singular> in <plural>` is ok most of the time. which gives us

```
...
for message in messages:
...
```

where do those messages come from? according to your code, they are the result of doing `self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode())`.

now that's a bummer. for starters, `('\r\n').encode()` is definitely the same as `'\r\n'.encode()`, which is one level of parentheses less. now this is certainly a constant, so why compute it anew on each turn? it might also be better to decode all of the buffer return by `irc.recv()` instead of first splitting and then decoding line-by-line.

but that's secondary to the point in question. importantly: whatever low-level code is needed to give you the next list of lines from `irc`, it should probably not appear in this spot. rather, something like

```
messages = self.irc.get_messages()
```

or maybe

```
messages = <SOME_LIBRARY>.get_irc_messages( self.irc )
```

would be appropriate. the details are, of course, subject to many contentious discussions. personally, i try to not conflate my data—stateful objects of mostly generic types with no functionality tacked unto them—on the one hand and my libraries—stateless collections of named pieces of functionality—on the other. the *Simple Made Easy* presentation linked above makes that exactly same point, btw, and manages to argue convincingly, too. (aside: of course this flies into the face of current mainstream OOP thinking—but google for Yegge's *Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns* if you believe `OOP ≡ good` *n'importe quois*.)

the present method is all about *answering* messages, not *receiving* them. think of it like a Yours Truly column in a newspaper: here we are in the office that thinks up and compiles answers to be sent out to the readers; those who open the incoming papermail, pick up the telephone and sift through the email have a whole different job taking place in another office. therefore, how to open an envelope should *not* be something you should implement *in this spot*. outsourcing is required.

whether or not you want to make that `messages` variable explicit or conflate it to an inline API call depends on a number factors like space available and whether you want to recycle that return value at another point in the routine. this looks fine to me:

```
...
for message in self.irc.get_messages():
...
```

the `for ... in` will transparently work with generators and list-returners alike, which is good.

always think of your code in terms of the most general, yet unbloated, most modularized, yet not 'atomized' ways.

if i was to write test cases against your code, i would definitely single out that `irc.recv` part and test it separately. think of your code in this way: what are good modules, each with a single concern and a reasonable level of isolation, sound call parameters, that make for good testability? what are reasonable names for the part of my code?—if you keep to this, your code will just stop nesting too deeply, all by itself.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I appreciate code readability. I took out the needless parenthesis. However, I still need to decode each message individually because if a unicode decode exception occurs, I would only lose that message and not 100 messages or however many would be in the iterable at the time.

Comment: i see. a valid concern. could it be that spurious decoding errors—if they occur—are caused by incomplete buffers being transferred? byte buffers that come over the wire may be truncated at any byte boundary and thus cut through a utf-8 byte sequence. if that should prove true for your application, it would be advisable to seek for the last occurrence of a utf-8 start byte, cut the message off there, and store the remaining bytes (maybe up until the last line break, and wait for bytes that complete that message)

Comment: That's absolutely what it is. I just got a 2-for-1 on this question!